# Проблемы с юникодом на localhost

Tags: веб-программирование, кодировка, utf-8, localhost, aiohttp

При просмотре сайта с localhost ломаются русские символы, превращаясь в кракозябры, при этом на хостинге всё ок.
Проблема на windows, хостинг на ubuntu, но решения этой проблемы для windows у меня найти не вышло.
Сайт на Python/aiohttp.web.
Пробовал менять кодировку файлов в редакторе. 
Пробовал указывать charset в headers - при установке других кракозябры меняются, с указанным utf-8 всё как без указанного charset. Firefox определяет кодировку как юникод.
Теги lang и charset на всех страницах указаны.

Подскажите ещё какие-нибудь варианты решения, пожалуйста.

Comment: Как именно вы просматриваете сайт с localhost и каковы точные настройки этого localhost?

Comment: Просматриваю через браузер, localhost:8080/, а вот по настройкам я не знаю.

Comment: А откуда взялся порт 8080 и кто его слушает?